# find: excluding sub-directory from search

Tags: bash, find

The following script looks for all files with the `.pdb` extension and then moves them to the subfolder `$all_trr`.

```
dir=$(pwd)
all_trr=${dir}/PCA
find "$dir" -maxdepth 2 -name "*.pdb" -exec cp {} ${all_trr} \;
```

It results in the following issue:

```
cp: '/home/novikov-g/Bureau/bak_build/analyse/BAK_MD_memb_monoEXT_xy110_rep2/PCA/MD_6nax_apo_POPE_110A.pdb' et '/home/novikov-g/Bureau/bak_build/analyse/BAK_MD_memb_monoEXT_xy110_rep2/PCA/MD_6nax_apo_POPE_110A.pdb' identifient le même fichier
```

I've tried to

```
find "$dir" -maxdepth 2 -name "*A.pdb" -not -path "${all_trr}" -exec cp {} ${all_trr} \;
```

but it did not resolve my issue

How to instruct `find` to ignore the "${all_trr}" ?

Comment: Didn't you ask this already a few minutes ago and receive exactly the same response?

Comment: well I edited my question with the solution that I've tried (from the proposed topic) but it did not resolve my issue..

Comment: Try this: `find "$dir" -maxdepth 2 \( -name  "$all_trr" -prune -o -name "*A.pdb" \) -exec cp {} "$all_trr" \;`

Comment: The solution you said you tried works for me here; probably there are some additional details you have not included.

Comment: find: warning: ‘-name’ matches against basenames only, but the given pattern contains a directory separator (‘/’), thus the expression will evaluate to false all the time.  Did you mean ‘-wholename’?